# What is the new name for this-expression-file-name?

Tags: racket

I need the name of the function that returns the path of the expression. In the old mzscheme days the two functions were called `this-expression-file-name` and `this-expression-source-directory` but what are they named in Racket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still find `this-expression-file-name` and `this-expression-source-directory` in `mzlib/etc`.  But usually now you'd use `define-runtime-path` to handle `this-expression-source-directory`, and direct access to the syntax object for the file name.

Comment: Of course: runtime-path ! I had forgotten the new name. In the mean time I sort of reimplemented it with (resolved-module-path-name
                           (module-path-index-resolve
                            (syntax-source-module #'here)))))